# Typescript - Importing third-party modules - Name autocomplete VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, import

While working with typescript in Visual Studio Code, I don't get module name autocomplete when importing 3rd party modules.

For example in:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
```

I have to type full module name ('react-router-dom') while in plain JS I got suggestions.

Is this standard behavior of TS or is there any option to enable this autocomplete for example in tsconfig.json?

[EDIT]

This is example of my node tsconfig.json file

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020" ,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true ,
    "outDir": "./dist" ,
    "strict": true ,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true ,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Can you post your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: But you should be able to get autocomplete, which version of TypeScript do you have installed?

Comment: I attached my tsconfig here. I've got 3.9.6v of TS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution.
In my vscode settings I've got unchecked:

```
TypeScript > Suggest: Paths
```

I don't know why, I have never been changing any settings of TS in my vscode editor.
Problem solved.

[EDIT]
Path Intellisense sets this option to false on install. In my case everything is working nice, only when I return to default TypeScript > Suggest > Paths: true.

Answer (score 0):

Type your word "Router" in your code and point the cursor at the end of the word and press `Ctrl + space` to auto-complete. the autocomplete will automatically include the imports for you.
even for 3rd party lib also in VSCode.

Comment: I know that, I'm using this everytime but in TS files while pressing "ctrl + space" nothing happens. I'm not getting any IDE suggestions, that is my problem.